# ruby conditional validation has_and_belong_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am having two models, User and Role,

In Role Model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

In the User model,

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles 
validates_presence_of :name, :if => "roles.map(&:name).include?(\"manager\")"
```

My problem is that I can add a "manager" role to the roles of user, and it will go through. In the console when I call

```
sampleUser.roles << managerRole
```

It goes thorough and saves in the db. when I call

```
sampleUser.valid?
```

I get false,

My understanding is that because roles_users is a separate table, nothing on the user is getting updated, so the user validations will not be used.
Any idea how t get around this problem and make user whatever goes to the db is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you can't access records through the HABTM relationship till the HABTM link is saved. What you can do is use an after_save callback to validate associated records and rollback the transaction if any validations fail.

See http://mattberther.com/2012/09/09/validating-habtm-relationships-with-rails-3x

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use

```
gem 'rolify'
gem 'cancan'
```

https://github.com/EppO/rolify

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

With those Gems it is very easy to handle roles in User Models.

Ryan Bates, author of cancan, has an awesome screencast about that issue:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan